# Angularjs - delete searched object from json array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm using a ng-change directive to get an object that change. When i get it i have to check if exists in another array of objects, and if it does i have to delete from it.
what can i do? i tried with indexOf but it didn't work.

```
//@Param ObjectItem: change object from UI using ng-change
$scope.itemValue = function (ObjectItem) {

    //collection of required items
    var requiredItem = dataPublicationService.getRequired();

    //check if item exist in collection. DIDN'T WORK!
    if(requiredItem.indexOf(publi) !== -1){

          //get found index
          var idx = requiredItem.indexOf(publi);

      //delete founded item.
      requiredItem.splice(idx, 1);
    }
};
```

What other solution can i implement?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The `indexOf` function doesn't delete from an array, it just finds the index of the given object if found. You might consider [filtering the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and testing for a match, rather than relying on `indexOf` to find a matching object.

Once you find your record, you need to actually alter the array using something like [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: Yes i know, the thing is to found that item in the json array to delete it after i found it. I update the code.